# Is there a theory in physcics that has not a mathematical theory?

Tags: mathematical-physics, philosophy

On person said to me that there is some theory in physics that they have not a good formalization yet, i.e. there is not a mathematical theory that covered them. Is this true? If yes, then without a mathematical theory how they work through such theory? how they compute? thanks.

Comment: This person probably had [quantum field theory](http://bookstore.ams.org/surv-149) in mind.

Comment: They compute anyway, throw out "infinities", and if the answer agrees with experiment, who cares if the math is bogus?  (except those stuffy mathematicians)

Comment: Is there any physical theory that has a rigorous mathematical formulation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Of course. There are more phenomenons in physics that are not mathematically described. With a glance search in web, you find many unsolved problems (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_physics) which have not solved yet. The subjects like *fields theory*, *high-energy physics*, *particle*, *cosmology* are some of these problems. You might wants to know that physics is not axiomatized yet. This is one of Hilbert problems, that says

**Can physics be axiomatized?**

In my idea, this is one of the fundamental parts physics which must be discovered. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertsProblems.html